Azure app function - stuck on using storage blob on localhost
I have an azure app function, very basic that runs well when deployed but locally, when I'm sending a post request it just get stuck and eventually the whole shuts down with the message shown below. When I comment out the line from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, the whole works and a response is returned.
My code:
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse(
        body="response",
        status_code=200
    )

the function.json file:
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
      {
        "authLevel": "function",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": [
          "post"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "$return"
      }
  
    ]
  }

The command to trigger:
curl -X POST http://localhost:7071/api/TestFunc -H "Content-Type:application/json" -v -o -

The command window gets stuck in this operation. The azure environment is started in a venv using func host start.
The azure terminal shows: Executing 'Functions.TestFunc' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs. and nothing else after that.
Is there any more info that I can provide to help find the solution? Does someone know what I can do to solve this issue? Having to deploy everytime to test is annoying.
pip list:
azure-common              1.1.28
azure-communication-email 1.0.0
azure-core                1.30.1
azure-cosmos              4.6.0
azure-eventhub            5.11.7
azure-functions           1.19.0
azure-mgmt-core           1.4.0
azure-storage-blob        12.20.0
azure-storage-queue       12.9.0
certifi                   2024.2.2
cffi                      1.16.0
charset-normalizer        3.3.2
colorclass                2.2.2
cryptography              42.0.5
docopt                    0.6.2
idna                      3.7
isodate                   0.6.1
msrest                    0.7.1
mysql-connector           2.2.9
numpy                     1.26.4
oauthlib                  3.2.2
packaging                 24.0
pandas                    2.2.2
pip                       24.0
pip-upgrader              1.4.15
pycparser                 2.22
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0
python-http-client        3.3.7
pytz                      2024.1
requests                  2.31.0
requests-oauthlib         2.0.0
sendgrid                  6.11.0
setuptools                65.5.0
six                       1.16.0
starkbank-ecdsa           2.2.0
terminaltables            3.1.10
typing_extensions         4.11.0
tzdata                    2024.1
urllib3                   2.2.1


I tried a sample HTTP trigger function code and sent a post request successfully in local and in Azure Portal after deployment.
Code :
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
import tempfile

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        connection_string = os.environ["AzureWebJobsStorage"]
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
        container_name = "kamcontainer"
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

        if req.method == "POST":
            req_data = req.get_json()
            blob_name = req_data.get("blob_name", None)
            file_content = req_data.get("file_content", None)
            
            if not blob_name or not file_content:
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    body="Blob name or file content not provided",
                    status_code=400
                )
            file_data = file_content.encode()
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
                temp_file.write(file_data)

            with open(temp_file.name, "rb") as data:
                blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
                blob_client.upload_blob(data)
            logging.info(f"Uploaded blob: {blob_name}")
            os.unlink(temp_file.name)

            return func.HttpResponse(
                body=f"Blob '{blob_name}' uploaded successfully",
                status_code=200
            )
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                body="Method not allowed",
                status_code=405
            )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            body="Internal Server Error",
            status_code=500
        )

local.settings.json :
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connec_string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}

requirements.txt :
azure-functions
azure-storage-blob

Postman :
I sent the post request in Postman like below:

Output :

The blob uploaded successfully to the Azure storage as below.

Azure Portal :
I deployed the function to the function app and ran it successfully via Post request as below.


Blob storage :


@Mart Did you get a chance to look into the solution I provided?
